# unexpected null error coming in flutter web on stream builder ,working fine on android

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I have the below code in my profile page.
The code is working absolutely fine in android ,but on web when I open my profile page it is showing

**unexpected null value error** ,

The code which is pointing to error in debug console :

```
return Container(
  
  child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(profileId)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context,snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Container(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data!);

      return Scaffold(
        //all body widgets
      );
```

the debug console shows

```
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>>#556d2):
Unexpected null value.

The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>
lib/profile_page.dart:615
```

Comment: What is `lib/profile_page.dart:615` in the code you shared?

Comment: its the line which points to the code showing error on StreamBuilder.
The debug console points to this line where stream builder has started.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put this line `User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data!);` into `else`, like this:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) { // if snapshot has no data this is going to run
  return Container(
    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
    child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
else{ // if snapshot has data this is going to run
  User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data!);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check Firebase permissions for the web

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the rest of the code is working fine, but since only profile page uses stream builder ,it is pointing to it.so permission error is not possible.